# "Be everywhere" V "Be available everywhere"

Tags: adjectives

When referring to a feature request in software to make a particular functionality easily reachable in the UI, which statement is more correct between:

1. This feature should be available everywhere in the system.
2. This feature should be everywhere in the system.

Comment: What's the context? The sentences mean different things so which is "more correct" will depend on what you want the meaning to be.

Comment: Referring to a feature request in a software to make a particular functionality easily reachable in the UI

Answer (score 1):

I would say something like "accessible throughout the system". This means you leave out using "everywhere", unless you wanted to stress its physical presence.